# When I scroll the mouse Graphics removed of Textfield and dropdown from Table which I have set.Please help someone.Thanks in advanced

Tags: java, javafx-2

without Scroll Bar everything is fine But if there are more rows and use Scroll Bar in the table view and I scroll down or up it graphics of Textfield automatically removed.

```
 public class ComboBoxRefresh extends Application {

    TableColumn answerTypeCol; 

    TableColumn answerCol; 
    ObservableList<String> answerSelectList;

    ComboBox comboBox;

    TextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Table Cell With Multiple Components");

         TableView<AnswerOption> table = new TableView<AnswerOption>();

         table.setEditable(true);

          final ObservableList<AnswerOption> data = 
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new AnswerOption("A", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("1", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("78", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("D", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("A", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("2", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("24", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("D", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("A", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("7", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("123", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("D", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("A", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("3", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("123", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("D", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("A", "Multiple Choice"),
                        new AnswerOption("5", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("123", "Free Text"),
                        new AnswerOption("D", "Multiple Choice")
                    );

        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();

        gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        gridpane.setHgap(5);

        gridpane.setVgap(5);

        answerSelectList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("A", "B", "C", "D", "INVALID_ANSWER", "NO_ANSWER");

        answerCol = new TableColumn();
        answerCol.setText("Answers");
        answerCol.setMinWidth(210);
        answerCol.setEditable(true);
        answerCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("answers"));

        answerCol.setCellFactory( new Callback<TableColumn<String, String>, TableCell<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<String, String> call(TableColumn<String, String> arg0) {
                return new anyMethod();
            }
        });

        answerTypeCol = new TableColumn();

        answerTypeCol.setText("Answers Type");
        answerTypeCol.setMinWidth(210);
        answerTypeCol.setEditable(true);
        answerTypeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("answersType"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(answerCol, answerTypeCol);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene =new Scene(root, 500, 550);
        gridpane.add(table, 1, 5,1,20 );
        root.getChildren().addAll(gridpane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
   }


    private class anyMethod extends TableCell <String, String>{

        public anyMethod(){

            comboBox = new ComboBox();
            textField = new TextField();
            comboBox.setItems(answerSelectList);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                 if (empty) {
                setText(null);
               setGraphic(null);
                System.out.println("In empty");
             } else {
                if( getTableView().getColumns().get(1).getCellData(getIndex()).toString().startsWith("M")){

                 System.out.println("Making ComboBox");
                 setGraphic(comboBox);
                }
                else{
                    setGraphic(textField);
                }
             }

        }

    }


    public static class AnswerOption {
        private final SimpleStringProperty answers;
        private final SimpleStringProperty answersType;


        private AnswerOption(String answers, String answersType) {
            this.answers = new SimpleStringProperty(answers);
            this.answersType = new SimpleStringProperty(answersType);
        }

        public String getAnswers() {
            return answers.get();
        }
        public void setAnswers(String answers) {
            this.answers.set(answers);
        }

        public String getAnswersType() {
            return answersType.get();
        }
        public void setAnswersType(String answersType) {
            this.answersType.set(answersType);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make combobox and textfield members of anyMethod class, because after scrolling updateItem() sets the only existing combobox to each cell which cause visual mangling.

Comment: Ok i have made textfield and combobox members of anymethod class. but textfield still hides automatically . i have changed code as below.

if (empty) {
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(null);
   } else {
    if (getTableView().getColumns().get(1).getCellData(getIndex())
      .toString().startsWith("M")) {
     ComboBox combo=new ComboBox();
     combo.setItems(namesChoiceList);
     setGraphic(combo);
     setVisible(true);
    } else {
     TextField text=new TextField();
     setGraphic(text); 
     text.setText("hello"); 
     setVisible(true);
    }
   }

Comment: @Ifran Could provide your new code? It's better to see the whole picture.